# Conditionally required fields in Eve schema

Tags: python, eve

I implemented the recently committed `'dependencies': {'attr': 'val'}` support, but it's not working for my use case. Here's what I'd like to do:

```
schema = {
    'attr1': {'type': 'string', 'required': True, 'allowed': ['Foo', 'Bar']},
    'attr2': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True, 'default': 1,
              'dependencies': {'attr1': 'Foo'}}
}

object = {
    'attr1': 'Bar'
}
```

When I POST `object` to an endpoint with `schema`, it fails with `"attr2": "field 'type' is required with values: Foo"`. I want it to only fail if `attr1: 'Foo'` as in my dependencies dict.

I think Eve might be populating `attr2` with the default value `1` specified in the schema and that's why it's throwing this error, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on Cerberus 0.8-dev:

```
from cerberus import Validator

schema = {
    'attr1': {'type': 'string', 'required': True, 'allowed': ['Foo', 'Bar']},
    'attr2': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True, 'dependencies': {'attr1': 'Foo'}}
}

object = {
    'attr1': 'Bar'
}

v = Validator(schema)
v.validate(object)
True
```

Then I tried:

```
object = {
    'attr1': 'Bar',
    'attr2': 1
}

v.validate(object)
False

v.errors
{'attr2': "field 'attr1' is required with values: Foo"}

object = {
    'attr1': 'Foo',
    'attr2': 1
}

v.validate(object)
True
```

Make sure you're on v0.8 though, this won't work on 0.7.2 which is the current release available on PyPI (which also means that this won't be available in Eve until Cerberus 0.8 is released and Eve 0.5 updates its Cerberus requirements).

Comment: Edited with more examples

Comment: Ah, in the process of creating a simple example I left out one detail: setting `'default': 1` on attr2. I've updated my example. When you run this now (with Eve) you'll see the error. The problem appears to be that even if an attribute's dependency isn't met, a default value is populated and the validator complains about it. Shouldn't Eve check dependencies are met before populating default values?